# Python masking of 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, boolean

Say I have 2 numpy arrays

```
a = [0, 2, 4, 6]
```

and

```
b = [0.03, 0.78, 0.25, 0.47, 0.98, 0.58, 0.63]
```

I want to return a 3rd array that checks where the indices of array a are in b and returns the value of that indices in b like below:

```
c = [0.3, 0.25, 0.98, 0.63]
```

I have tried

```
for i in range(len(b)):
if b[i] == a.any():
    c=[I]
```

but get all 0's.

Comment: Simple as `c = b[a]`?

Comment: list indices can't be lists

Comment: OP is talking about numpy arrays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use

```
c = b[a]
```

This will be a view to b, so if you change c, you also change b. If you don't want this, use `.copy()`

```
c = b[a].copy()
```

Comment: Nice. For completion sake, you can include an example that creates an independent list.

Answer (score 1):

using list comprehension

```
a = [0, 2, 4, 6]
b = [0.03, 0.78, 0.25, 0.47, 0.98, 0.58, 0.63]
c = [b[i] for i in a]
```

Comment: doesn't that only work for lists and not numpy arrays?

Comment: the original question was edited to add `numpy` i wasn't aware before